# Microsoft Visual Studio Code Remote-SSH could not establish connection

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I am new to SSH. I am trying to connect to a Linux cluster at my school using remote-ssh in vscode. I am able to connect to a random Linux machine at my school using remote-ssh. I am able to connect to the Linux cluster just fine using PuTTY or Ubuntu. However, I keep getting errors with vscode.

It seems like it is trying to make a directory "home/user/", which isn't allowed. Is this a correct interpretation? How can I stop it from trying to connect to that directory? Or can a specify a different directory to go to?

Other students in my class are using vscode and have the same config settings, so I do not know why I am getting these errors specifically.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
[15:39:07.990] Log Level: 2
[15:39:07.993] remote-ssh@XXXX
[15:39:07.993] win32 x64
[15:39:07.994] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+cluster", attempt 1
[15:39:07.994] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[15:39:07.994] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[15:39:07.995] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[15:39:07.995] "remote.SSH.sshPath": undefined
[15:39:07.995] "remote.SSH.sshConfigurationFile": C:\Users\user\.ssh\config
[15:39:07.995] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[15:39:07.995] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[15:39:07.995] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[15:39:07.995] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[15:39:07.995] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[15:39:07.995] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[15:39:07.996] SSH Resolver called for host: cluster
[15:39:07.996] Setting up SSH remote "cluster"
[15:39:08.008] Using commit id "XXX" and quality "stable" for server
[15:39:08.012] Install and start server if needed
[15:39:11.878] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[15:39:11.906] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5

[15:39:11.911] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\user\.ssh\config"
[15:39:11.911] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 63620 -F "C:\Users\user\.ssh\config" "cluster" bash
[15:39:11.914] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[15:39:11.952] > 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[15:39:11.953] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[15:39:11.962] > 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
[15:39:12.185] > cluster's password: 
[15:39:12.186] Showing password prompt
[15:39:15.805] Got password response
[15:39:15.806] "install" wrote data to terminal: "*******************"
[15:39:15.823] > 
> 
[15:39:16.275] > Could not chdir to home directory /cluster/home/user: No such file or directory
> 
[15:39:16.292] > XXXXXXXXXXX: running
> 
[15:39:16.515] > mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/cluster/home/user’
[15:39:16.522] > mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/cluster/home/user’Creating the server install dir failed...
> XXXXXXXXXX: start
> exitCode==34==
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId====
> arch====
> tmpDir==/run/user/XXXXX==
> platform====
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime====
> XXXXXXXXXXX: end
> : Permission denied
> 
[15:39:16.523] Received install output: 
exitCode==34==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId====
arch====
tmpDir==/run/user/XXXXX==
platform====
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime====

[15:39:16.524] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[15:39:16.528] Resolver error: Error: 
    at Function.Create (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1\out\extension.js:1:64328)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1\out\extension.js:1:63022)
    at q (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1\out\extension.js:1:296373)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1\out\extension.js:1:294221
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1\out\extension.js:1:407055)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1\out\extension.js:1:297912)
    at async c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1\out\extension.js:127:110485
[15:39:16.534] ------
```